# how to preset the register arrays in Verilog?

Tags: arrays, verilog

I am trying to define a register file, 32-bit wide 32-bit deep, in Verilog. How to preset all the values to zero or to any value I want with/without a for loop?

[image]

Here's my code, I tried but failed:

```
module register_file(rna, rnb, qa, qb);
  input [4:0]rna;
  input [4:0]rnb;
  output [31:0]qa;
  output [31:0]qb;
  genvar i;
  reg [31:0]registers[0:31];
  assign registers[0]=32'b0;
  registers[1]=32'b0;
  registers[2]=32'b0;
  registers[3]=32'b0;
endmodule
```

Comment: Just how to preset all the register values in a convenient way. Both fixing the syntax error or writing totally different code are fine.

Comment: Sorry I am new here.

Comment: If all the `registers`' bits are going to be driven in the same `always`, place a `for` loop in the first `if` clause, with the `registers`' address being the loop variable. This way, it's suitable for a register file which has the same preset/reset value for every word in it. If you're going to preset each individual word with a different value, it's better to use a customized method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set all the bits to be 0 in a two-dimensional array in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356857/how-to-set-all-the-bits-to-be-0-in-a-two-dimensional-array-in-verilog)

Comment: Yes, I learned that for loop should be put in a block, like always and initial. Otherwise an error may happen.

Answer (score 0):

A usual way to preset register values is done using clocks and a reset signal. For example:

```
reg [31:0]registers[0:31];
integer i;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
        for (i = 0; i < 31; i = i + 1)
            registers[i] <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        // do some real work with registers here
    end
 end
```

in some cases you might want to do some initial setting in your testbench initial block

```
    initial begin
      for (i = 0; ...) registers[i]= 0;
    end
```

The above is not usually synthesizable.

There are few other ways available in System Verilog.

Comment: I may do the initialization in testbench. Thanks for the instruction.